# How can I include a file (#include <>) using a variable path in DXL (IBM DOORS)?

Tags: include, ibm-doors

Basically, what I do is executing a DXL from a batch file. That batch file, which gets some paths from a java code, sends the paths to the DXL.

I get OK the paths in DXL (it is actually a normal string), and now I want to use those path string in order to make some #include.

So, if I have a variable:

```
string a = "MY/PATH/IS/OK"
```

I want to use that **a** to make an include:

```
#include <a/whatever.inc>
```

Does anybody know how to?

Besides...
The includes I want to do is in the same folder as the DXL script which has to do the things above...could I use something like:

```
#include <.\the_include_file.inc>
```

Or something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DXL, the `#include` command is evaluated before any other DXL command is evaluated (basically, the preprocessor only takes the content of the referenced file and replaces the line containing the `#include` with the content of the script.
So, a snippet like

```
string a = ..read_some_value_from_a_file..
#include <{a}/whatever.inc>
```

will not work (well, only inside an eval_ statement, but that's too complicated)

I think the easiest way to solve your problem is to call your java code before DOORS is started and then call doors.exe with the `-addins` parameter, see https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21324525 and https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21421641 for details and alternatives. Also, have a look at Louie Landale's summary at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=d43c725f-bd74-4c1a-88d5-51fdf8eed0b9 which also mentions the environment variables you can use.

Update:
some time ago, we made some tests about the order where dxl files are searched, here is some script excerpt.

```
    string sCur                 = currentDirectory()             ; buf += sCur             ; buf += ";"
    string sInst                = (getenv "DOORSHOME") "\\lib\\dxl"; buf += sInst            ; buf += ";"
    string sAddinsCmd           = (getenv "DOORSADDINS")         ; buf += sAddinsCmd       ; buf += ";"        
    string sAddins              = (getenv "ADDINS")              ; if (null sAddinsCmd) buf += sAddins; buf += ";"

    string sProjectAddinsCmd    = (getenv "DOORSPROJECTADDINS")  ; buf += sProjectAddinsCmd; buf += ";"
    string sProjectAddins       = (getenv "PROJECTADDINS")       ; if (null sProjectAddinsCmd) buf += sProjectAddins   ; buf += ";"
```

So, if you start DOORS with the commands

```
C:\> D:
D:\> cd \temp
D:\temp> "c:\Program Files\IBM\DOORS\9.6\bin\doors.exe" -addins E:\scripts
```

and you have an include statement with a relative path, i.e. `#include <src/lib/hello.inc>`, DOORS first tries to find a directory src in D:\temp, then in c:\Program Files\IBM...\lib\dxl, then in E:\scripts.

If your include statement has an absolute path, i.e. `#include <c:/myscripts/lib/dxl/goodmorning.inc>` or `#include <\\\\myservername\\myshare\\dxllib\\helloibm.inc>`, it will look exactly in these locations.

Comment: But @Mike, is there a way to include the files that are in the same folder...I mean a kind of:  #include <./whatever.inc>

Comment: #include <whatever.inc> or #include <./whatever.inc> or #include <.\\whatever.inc> with "." being one of the directories mentioned in the update of my answer

Comment: one more comment: DXL has no concept of a "base path" of a script, DXL does not know anything about files where code resides apart from #include-Statements, and even the #include is removed from the preprocessor.
In Perl, you could say "perl c:\allmyscripts\helloworld.pl", and inside the perl script you could ask for the directory where helloworld.pl resides (dirname $0) and then "push @INC, dirname $0". This is not possible in DXL.